# Handling OnItemTouch For a Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to add `OnItemTouch` in this tutorial:

http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/recycler-view-handling-onitemtouch-for.html

final code:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;  // Declaring Variable to Understand which View is being worked on
    // IF the viaew under inflation and population is header or Item
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;

    private String mNavTitles[]; // String Array to store the passed titles Value from MainActivity.java
    private int mIcons[];       // Int Array to store the passed icons resource value from MainActivity.java

    private String name;        //String Resource for header View Name
    private int profile;        //int Resource for header view profile picture
    private String email;       //String Resource for header view email
    Context context;


    // Creating a ViewHolder which extends the RecyclerView View Holder
    // ViewHolder are used to to store the inflated views in order to recycle them

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        int Holderid;

        TextView textView;
        ImageView imageView;
        ImageView profile;
        TextView Name;
        Context contxt;


        public ViewHolder(View itemView,int ViewType,Context c) {                 // Creating ViewHolder Constructor with View and viewType As a parameter
            super(itemView);
            contxt = c;
            itemView.setClickable(true);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            // Here we set the appropriate view in accordance with the the view type as passed when the holder object is created

            if(ViewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
                textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowText); // Creating TextView object with the id of textView from item_row.xml
                imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowIcon);// Creating ImageView object with the id of ImageView from item_row.xml
                Holderid = 1;                                               // setting holder id as 1 as the object being populated are of type item row
            }
            else{


                Name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);         // Creating Text View object from header.xml for name
                       // Creating Text View object from header.xml for email
                profile = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.circleView);// Creating Image view object from header.xml for profile pic
                Holderid = 0;                                                // Setting holder id = 0 as the object being populated are of type header view
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(contxt,"The Item Clicked is: "+getPosition(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }

    MyAdapter(String Titles[], int Icons[], String Name, int Profile, Context passedContext){ // MyAdapter Constructor with titles and icons parameter
        // titles, icons, name, email, profile pic are passed from the main activity as we
        mNavTitles = Titles;                //have seen earlier
        mIcons = Icons;
        name = Name;
        profile = Profile;                     //here we assign those passed values to the values we declared here
        this.context = passedContext;

        //in adapter
    }

    //Below first we ovverride the method onCreateViewHolder which is called when the ViewHolder is
    //Created, In this method we inflate the item_row.xml layout if the viewType is Type_ITEM or else we inflate header.xml
    // if the viewType is TYPE_HEADER
    // and pass it to the view holder

    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_row,parent,false); //Inflating the layout

            ViewHolder vhItem = new ViewHolder(v,viewType,context); //Creating ViewHolder and passing the object of type view

            return vhItem; // Returning the created object

            //inflate your layout and pass it to view holder

        } else if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {

            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.header,parent,false); //Inflating the layout

            ViewHolder vhHeader = new ViewHolder(v,viewType,context); //Creating ViewHolder and passing the object of type view

            return vhHeader; //returning the object created


        }
        return null;

    }

    //Next we override a method which is called when the item in a row is needed to be displayed, here the int position
    // Tells us item at which position is being constructed to be displayed and the holder id of the holder object tell us
    // which view type is being created 1 for item row
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if(holder.Holderid ==1) {                              // as the list view is going to be called after the header view so we decrement the
            // position by 1 and pass it to the holder while setting the text and image
            holder.textView.setText(mNavTitles[position - 1]); // Setting the Text with the array of our Titles
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(mIcons[position -1]);// Settimg the image with array of our icons
        }
        else{

            holder.profile.setImageResource(profile);           // Similarly we set the resources for header view
            holder.Name.setText(name);

        }
    }

    // This method returns the number of items present in the list
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mNavTitles.length+1; // the number of items in the list will be +1 the titles including the header view.
    }


    // Witht the following method we check what type of view is being passed
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (isPositionHeader(position))
            return TYPE_HEADER;

        return TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    private boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
        return position == 0;
    }

}
```

but there is a problem with this code. I need, when user clicked on Items(in drawer), user to go to another activity. And here is my method:

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
                b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class));
                    }
                });
```

I can do this with Switch for each item.

But, how to achieve this?
(where can I put this method on `My Adaptor`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior would happen in your MyAdapter.ViewHolder class. Make the ViewHolder implement View.OnClickListener and then you can add on click behavior for the entire item. It looks like in your code you already have this method defined, so you just have to add your startActivity line inside the onClick method.

Comment: RecyclerView ViewHolder has a method `getPosition()`, use that to get the position of whatever element you clicked.

Comment: Check to make sure you actually changed the right code, the code you have in the question has the `The Item Clicked Is: ` text.

Comment: i was wrong and i added this method in Mainactivity and MyAdaptor.just, delete one method from mainactivity and it work now.tnx